# How to execute exclusive-OR operation programmatically

Tags: java, android

How can I programmatically on Java execute next operation:

The two blocks are exclusive-OR added:

```
05 92 38 9F FF FF FF FF
00 00 40 00 00 12 34 56
--------------------------------
05 92 78 9F FF ED CB A9
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are those?  Arrays of bytes?

Comment: A 16-digit blockis made from the digit 0, the length of the PIN, the PIN, and a pad
character (hexadecimal F). For example, for the 5-digit PIN 92389, the blockis:
0592 389F FFFF FFFF

Comment: Another 16-digit block is made from four zeros and the 12 right-most digits of the account number, excluding the checkdigit. For example, for the 13-digit account number 4000
0012 3456 2, where the check digit is 2, the block is:
0000 4000 0012 3456

Comment: I not well undestand what is difference between arrays and bytes for this operation. Can you explain me.
I am sorry for dull question.

Comment: Can anyone show stupid user(me) sample of this operation. I promise not asking such questions anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The [exclusive-or operator is `^`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.22.1), e.g.:

```
a = 1 ^ 2;
```

Assuming your first two rows are arrays, simply create a third array of the same dimension and loop through performing the operation and saving the result. (Or loop through performing the operation and storing back to one of the arrays, if you don't need a separate result array.)

Comment: A 16-digit blockis made from the digit 0, the length of the PIN, the PIN, and a pad character (hexadecimal F). 
Another 16-digit block is made from four zeros and the 12 right-most digits of the account number, excluding the checkdigit.

Comment: I have these two blockes stored as String. Can you show me how to execute this operations and save result as String.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user: People mostly aren't going to write code for you, that's your job. People are happy to help you figure out why **your** code may not do what you expect. For your coding: You can split strings on a delimiter (e.g., the spaces between the pairs of digits) using [`String#split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)). Then you can convert individual hex strings to actual values via [`Integer.parseInt`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) passing in radix = 16.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I am sorry for my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XOR operator on the two blocks of bits. The bitwise XOR operator in Java is `^`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: I have these two blockes stored as String. Can you show me how to execute this operations and save result as String.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question is closed.Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Java's Bitwise XOR Operator `^`.

```
A   ^    B     =   C

1        0         1
0        1         1
0        0         0
1        1         0
```

Comment: I have these two blockes stored as String. Can you show me how to execute this operations and save result as String.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question is closed.Thank you for reply.